# Scroll function disabled locally, still working on live site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi all I have to make updates to a site one of my predecessors created years ago. The smooth scroll has failed to load its resources thankfully the live site is still functioning as it should http://www.asla.org/greenroof/index.html

I also just want to add that the local files threw no errors about a month ago when I last checked locally.

I will need to upload the index.html file along with new images to make the updates. I assume this will not change or disable the functionality of the live site.

Currently just trying to get the scroll to work locally. This cursor .cur element I cant find anywhere so I assume its part of a jquery library.

Any ideas? Thanks again.

Here are the errors I'm getting I have no idea how to fix this. Help would be appreciated.

console

[image]

index.html

[image]

jqueryLoader.js line 23 and 109

[image]

[image]

jquery.tools.min.js line 174

```
e&&e.document?e.document.compatMode==="CSS1Compat"&&e.document.documentElement["client"+b]||e.document.body["client"+b]:e.nodeType===9?Math.max(e.documentElement["client"+b],e.body["scroll"+b],e.documentElement["scroll"+b],e.body["offset"+b],e.documentElement["offset"+b]):f===w?c.css(e,d):this.css(d,typeof f==="string"?f:f+"px")}});A.jQuery=A.$=c})(window);
```

Here is also the CSS

[image]

Server doesnt even have /cursor directory from path specified by console

[image: No Images Folder]

[image: No Cursors Folder]

Update 3/25/15
Local site scroll works fine returning no errors when set up on local web server MAMP. Quite strange how accessing the site via file:// stopped working randomly.

[image: Arrow images appear and horizontal scroll is restored]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to do a local test you can go through the css and rename

```
background-image: url (../images/cursor/rightArrowoutline.png);
background-image: url (../images/cursor/curspr_arrow_right.cur)
background-image: url (../images/cursor/curspr_arrow_left.cur)
```

to

```
background-image: url ('http://www.example.com/greenroof/images/cursor/curspr_arrow_right.cur')
background-image: url ('http://www.example.com/greenroof/images/cursor/curspr_arrow_left.cur')
```

example.com would be the name of the live domain.

If you want a production ready file when you are done, I would set up a local web server. Check out all of your source files and make a local version of the site.

MAMP is a pretty fast setup.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP

Update: 3/10
It looks like the cursors are in two places on your servers files system. 
Do you have both directories with the files?

[image: Looks like the cursors are in two places]

Comment: Thanks will try tomorrow, do you have any idea why or how the .cur files could be missing locally all of the sudden?

Comment: No idea. Can you find the missing files on your local machine? You can always just copy them there from the live site. Do you have source control for this project? The last dev might have committed some unfinished changes. I'll check out your site and see if I see anything.

Comment: thing is I checked locally and on the server and saw no .../cursors directories thats why it baffles me. Check edit to the OP

Comment: You need to get you local environment up to date with the live server environment. 

You server has a directory 

`/greenroof/css/images/cursors/`

and

`/images/cursors/cursor_arrow_right.cur`

The network requests show that it exists. If you don't have that maybe the orig dev didn't put that in their source that you have.

Comment: I discovered the scroll is just disabled on my mac, if accessed on another machine locally everything worse just fine. Has anyone ever encountered this before, do you know a solution ?

Comment: Are you accessing the file via the file system, clicking and opening it or are you running a local web server?

Comment: Through the file system file://Users etc . . .

Comment: Try setting up a local web server and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks installing MAMP now and will let you know the results. Any idea what could have changed to make the file system not work and throw all those errors on one particular machine ?

Comment: Setting up on MAMP was the solution, file:// issue still unknown but at least I can see what I'm doing now when I work. Thanks @whoacowboy